# Помогите вписать в формулу переменные из других файлов

Tags: python

Нужна помощь специалистов, язык пайтон. Пусть формула выглядит таким образом: a = b - c. Значения a,b,c (обыкновенные числа) нужно импортировать с других файлов. Как это сделать на питоне, напишите пример кода, пожалуйста

Comment: с переменной "a" тупанул, естественно нелогичный пример получился, но на суть вопроса не влияет

Comment: Здесь не пишут примеры кода, здесь помогают с решением проблем, которые возникли у тебя при написании кода.

Comment: '''нужно импортировать с других файлов''' какие проблемы вызывает ? какие ошибки выдаёт ? что уже пробовали ?

Comment: а в каком виде они в другом файле (числа) записаны то? все в одном файле или в разных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос не очень. Но можно и ответить:

```
import data_modul

def formula(string, **kwargs):
    for key in kwargs.keys():
        string = string.replace('{'+key+'}', '{kwargs["'+key+'"]}')
    string = 'f"""'+string+'"""'
    string = eval(string) 
    return string

print(formula('a+b', a=data_modul.CONST_a, b=data_modul.CONST_b))
```

Модуль **`data_modul`**:

```
CONST_a = 17
CONST_b = 79
```